# Android, How to share file to another user without locking screen by using a progress dialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog, fileshare

I want to implement a system where user can **send file to server without locking the screen** by using  progress dialog of android.

Viber, What's app , skype share file from one user to another without locking the screen using only one progress dialog, they use a small progress dialog for every file and they don't lock the screen.. How to implement that?

A sample screenshot is given bellow.

[image]

The red arrow shows the progress dialog what I want to implement in my system to share files..

Comment: Not sure but you can try if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13709992/1777090) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481723/file-upload-progress-bar-android-similar-to-whatsapp) helps :)